# Unable to use remote.require() with TypeScript

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript, electron

I'm developing an Electron application in TypeScript, and I've run into a frustrating issue.

I'm attempting to run a module from a renderer process with the following code:

```
import { remote } from 'electron'

const myModule = remote.require('./my-module')
```

The only way I can use [`remote.require`](https://electronjs.org/docs/api/remote#remoterequiremodule) with my module, is by adding `module.exports = myModule` to the `my-module.ts` file.

```
// my-module.ts
export class myModule { ... }

module.exports = myModule
```

After adding the `module.exports = myModule` line, it causes errors where ever I import myModule with a standard TypeScript import.

For example

```
// main.ts
import { myModule } from './my-module'
// Error here
```

To fix this error, I can simply replace the import statement with

```
const myModule = require('./my-module')
```

But when I replace the import statement to the one above, my TypeScript does not recognise `myModule` and all it's members. The intelisense shows nothing for `myModule` and TypeScript throws a bunch of errors even though the program runs just fine.

---

**Some things to note:**

1. The contents of my tsconfig.json are:

   ```
   {
       "compilerOptions": {
           "target": "es5",
           "module": "commonjs",
           "moduleResolution": "node",
           "outDir": "./",
           "emitDecoratorMetadata": true,
           "experimentalDecorators": true,
           "alwaysStrict": true,
       },
       "exclude": [
           "node_modules"
       ]
   }
   ```
2. In the compiled JavaScript code, it results in something like the following when used with a TypeScript import statement:

   ```
   var my_module_1 = require("./my-module");
   my_module_1.myModule.foo('bar');
   ```

   Which gives me an error of `TypeError: Cannot read property 'sayHi' of undefined`.

   The JavaScript should look like this instead for it to work:

   ```
   var my_module_1 = require("./my-module");
   my_module_1.foo('bar');
   ```

---

How can I use `remote.require()` with TypeScript?

Comment: I think the problem is you are transpiling in esm, not commonjs. Check your compiled JS files to see if they contain `import/export` statement.

From your code, electron doesn't understand esm (as expected).

Comment: My `tsconfig.json` file has the following: `"target": "es5", "module": "commonjs", "moduleResolution": "node"` and the compiled JavaScript uses `var module = require('require');`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you implement your code in ESM and import it in commonjs (that's what `remote.require()` does), you will get the module namespace object:

```
// myModule.ts
export function foo() { ... }

// and to access the default export:
export default const boo = 'boo'

// consumer.js
const myModule = require('./myModule')

myModule = { foo() { ... }, default: 'boo' }
```

Therefore, your to use your `myModule` class, you need to do this:

```
const myModule = remote.require('./myModule')

const obj = new myModule.myModule()
const boo = myModule.default
```

UPDATE: `remote.require()` is a dynamic call, so TypeScript can't detect the type of the `myModule` and set it to `any`.

You can do the following to get the type back:

```
import * as MyModule from './myModule'
const myModule: typeof MyModule = remote.require('./myModule')
```

Comment: Yes this is correct, thank you very much. It might be worth mentioning that anything exported as default (`export default myModule`) must be referenced under `remote.require('./myModule').default`.

Comment: I only have one issue now.. the intelisense doesn't work when using `remote.require` in TypeScript. It doesn't throw any errors, but is there any way to fix this?

Comment: Updated answer.

Comment: Yep, I ended up doing exactly this, thank you so much for taking the time to answer this!